# Installing private dependencies with composer

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install a package I created into Symfony using composer, the package is a private git repository. The project already has some dependencies installed.
I followed the instructions depicted [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository).

How do I actually *install* the package?.

Lets say I put this on `composer.json`:

```
"repositories":[
  {
    "type":"git",
    "url":"git@mygitlab.com:myvendor/myproject.git"
  }
],
"require":{
  ...
  "myvendor/myproject":"dev-master",
  ...
}
```

If I run `composer require myvendor/myproject` nothing happens.
I'm trying to avoid deleting `composer.lock` and doing a `composer install` as there is one dependency that is broken, and deleting `composer.lock` will mean some mess.

Comment: Did you run `composer require myvendor/myproject` after you made the change to your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Yes, it says: `Could not find package myvendor/myproject at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability`

Comment: If you have no stable release, you need to reflect that in the require command: `composer require myvendor/myproject:dev-master`

Comment: Interesting: It says "The requested package myvendor/myproject could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.". I think I misunderstood Composer's docs. Do I need to have an explicit branch called "dev-master"?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you branch is called, but this must be reflected in the command argument. For example, if your branch were `develop`, you would use something like `composer require myvendor/myproject:dev-develop`

Comment: I think I messed up. Does the package's composer.json need to have the same name as the repo?

Comment: I am not sure I properly understand what you mean. But the value of the `name` key in that `composer.json` file (the one in your private Git repository) needs to be the same you are trying to require locally.

Comment: Got it... I am ashamed of how I messed up, I was on the package's directory instead of the project... that is why it did not work! Thanks for the info though, couldn't have made it without it!